# Where can I find updated TAR.rpm for Oracle VM Server?

Tags: rpm, tar, oracle-vm-server

I'm using tar for my incremental backup script on `Oracle VM Server 3.2.2` and it comes with `tar 1.15.1`

I need this command:

```
tar -cf drive-C.full.tar --no-check-device \
    --listed-incremental=drive-C.full.snapshot drive-C/
```

But I get this error:

```
tar: unrecognized option `--no-check-device'
```

---

Edit...

I'm doing incremental backups on VMs disks. I need the "no-check-device" because every time the vm disk .img file is mounted, the device numbers change and that messes up with tar's incremental backups.

Continues on:
[How to do incremental backup of .img files containing windows partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78919/how-to-do-incremental-backup-of-img-files-containing-windows-partition)

Comment: Why do you need that option?

Comment: I see. So you mount the img-file of a windows-vm ("C"?) (BTW: how?) before you backup the files of the filesystem within that image? There might be other ways to do this (mounting and even incremental backup).

Comment: First I backup the hole .img file. On incremental backups I mount windows C partition `mount /backup/win-vm/win-vm.img -o loop,offset=$(({STARTSECTOR * SECTOR_SIZE that I got from file and fdisk })) \
      /backup/win-vm/drive-C` and use tar with a level 1 snapshot file to get the changes. On an eventual restore, I'll just copy my base .img file and the level 1 tar archive.

Comment: Updating GNU tar does not help as none of the GNU tar versions supports incremental restores for non-trivial changes between two incrementals. I guess you better use `star` since star has been verified to support correct incremental restores for any kind of differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle Linux, which is the base of Oracle VM is based on RHEL 5.

Another clone is CentOS 5. Current version: 5.8.

But: current tar-Version there is 1.15.1, too.

So if you want to get a newer version you have to compile it.
For this you can include the CentOS-repositories into Oracle-Linux and install the needed compilation tools (gcc...).

OR try to get a way around using that "no-check-device" option.

**Update** 2013-06-07 about loopback-mounting:

Your problem with the changing major/minor propably arises because Oracle-VM itselv is dynamically using loopback-mounts by itselv. I would recommend the following steps:

1. `losetup` your backup-image to a high-numbered loopback-device (like /dev/loop50)
2. Do a `kpartx -av` on that device (this should give you a device for the Windows-C-partition)
3. Mount that partition ro (propably with ntfs-utils or newer)
4. Do your incementaly backup with `tar` or `rsync`.
5. `umount`
6. `kpartx -dv`
7. release the loopback-device with `losetup`

I will provide further details when I am on a CentOS-box (including your repository-question).

Comment: Compiling never was easy with me, but I'll try. But I think that in the end I'll have to see what rsync can do for me.

Comment: @GustavoFSx `rsync` is one of the tools I would have advised to take a look at. It has a mode where it can rsync differences within a file - like your image. Or you could manually mount your image with always the same major/minor...

Comment: So, OVM doesn't come with the standard repositories. Witch one has the "build-essentials"?

Comment: @GustavoFSx I will update my answer with that information. While I was experimenting with OVM I used the standard-repos for CentOS 5 to install the `snmpd`.

Comment: I was able to set up the repo from here http://public-yum.oracle.com/

Comment: Well, I managed compile tar, but I still have problems with it incremental backup. The uncompressed tars are 20GB for the full backup and 8.5GB for incremental. I'll create a new question soon, after I read 'man rsync'.

Comment: I've posted the new question

Answer (score 3):

Which hardware are you running this on Sparc or x86? I would guess that you're probably running Unbreakable Linux in which case you should be able to get an appropriate version of an RPM with x86 or Sparc.

Looking at this page would seem to indicate what I'm saying is correct, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26996_01/E18549/html/BABDDEGC.html. You also might want to just try running the command:

```
yum update tar
```

Oracle Unbreakable Linux is a derivative product from RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) so you should be able to install package built for CentOS (another deriviative product from RHEL). So long as it's the correct architecture.

Comment: Oracle VM Server 3.2.2 on x86_64

Comment: So you should be able to either do a `yum update tar` or get the appropriate x86_64 RPM from a CentOS repository. I would just download the tar RPM and install it directly.

Comment: Do you have the file `/etc/redhat-release`? If so what does it contain?

Comment: This would be the appropriate RPM for a RHEL6 derivative distro: http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-x86_64/tar-1.23-11.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: /etc/redhat-release contains: Oracle VM server release 3.2.2

Comment: Maybe I could use YUM, but I get: Repository 'ovm_repo' is missing name in configuration, using id
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: ovm_repo. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: Have you ever done a `yum update` on this system? I would go through this page, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26996_01/E18549/html/BABDDEGC.html and see if your system is configured correctly for yum updates.

Comment: No, YUM was never used. I'll see if I can set it up with the link you provided.