# How to do incremental backup of .img files containing windows partition?

Tags: backup, tar, virtualization, oracle-vm-server

On an OVS I have a few windows machines.

I want to create a full backup their .img disk files, thats done, .img.gz. Than I want to incrementally backup their C:/ partition, but thats not working.

The backup media is a tape drive installed on a remote windows machine accessible by FTP.

With help from my previous post I came up with the following commands for the first run:

```
cd /backup/win-vm-1/
losetup /dev/loop9 win-vm-1.img
kpartx -av /dev/loop9
mount /dev/mapper/loop9p2 drive-C/ -o ro
# Creates a 20Gb file
tar -cSmf drive-C.0.tar --no-check-device -g drive-C.0.snapshot drive-C/
umount -d drive-C/
kpartx -dv /dev/loop9
```

For the incremental backups I tried the same script but with this changes:

```
cp drive-C.0.snapshot drive-C.1.snapshot
tar -cSmf drive-C.1.tar --no-check-device -g drive-C.1.snapshot drive-C/
```

But doing this results in a 8.5GB file.

The changes made on the .img between the full and incremental backup were:

1. Boot machine
2. Create two .png files in one folder
3. Delete one .png file in another folder
4. Shutdown

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better solution?

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to backup the images incrementally externally. From inside the VM I think you can. Do you know for sure if you can do it this way? I think you'd have to setup a scheduled task inside of the windows VM and do a incremental from in there. For Linux VMs you can use this method: http://serverfault.com/questions/58660/incremental-backups-of-virtual-machines

Comment: I came across this solution: http://www.linux-kvm.org/wiki/images/b/b6/2011-forum-LiveBackup.pdf

Comment: You didn't boot the vm while you had the fs mounted in the host did you?

Comment: @slm I got some of the ideas from here: https://forums.oracle.com/message/10941581 But I wont be doing hot backups just yet.

Comment: @psusi No, I always unmount the .img file before booting.

Comment: @GustavoFSx - thanks for the link. Seems like you could make use of the ZFS methodology to do this, no?

Comment: I saw that on the discussion but didn't understand what it was about. I thought specific hardware/licence was needed. It isn't?

Comment: See what files are in the tar with tar -t.  Double check some of them to see if they really did change.

Comment: @psusi Tanks, I feel stupid now. tar -t didn't show anything so I `du -hl|less` and saw that some files do change, but are useless system logs, anti virus stuff. I should just do incremental backups of the Users folder.